# Получение элемента класса vector в параметризованном классе

Tags: stl, vector, c++

Есть класс:

```
template <typename T>
class cFunctionVector {
public:
    cFunctionVector()
    {
        functionsVector = new vector<T>();
    }

    cFunctionVector(vector<T> _functionsVector)
    {
        functionsVector = _functionsVector;
    }

    void addFunction(T _function)
    {
        functionsVector.resize(functionsVector.size()+1);
        functionsVector.push_back(_function);
    }

    int getAmount()
    {
        return functionsVector.size();
    }

    T getFunctionValue(int _number)
    {
        vector<T>::iterator it = functionsVector.begin(); //проблемная строка
        return *(it + _number);
    }
private:
    vector<T> functionsVector;
};
```

Компилятор ругается на отмеченную строку, вывод ошибки:

```
need 'typename' before 'std::vector<T>::iterator' because 'std::vector<T>' is a dependent scope
```

метод писался для получения i-го элемента поля `functionsVector`, и ругается, я так понимаю, компилятор на то, что для итератора не задан явно тип (`int`, `float` и т.д.), а стоит некий класс T. Но в том то и дело, что вектор в данном классе может быть любого типа. Как можно это исправить? Или я вообще неверно пытаюсь вернуть i-й элемент?

Comment: А зачем resize() перед push_back() ?

Да и в getFunctionValue можно просто return functionsVector[\_number];

Comment: @MorkOFF48, а Вы не пробовали подключить `<functional>` и использовать класс `std::function`? Почему-то мне кажется, что Вы уже много дней изобретаете велосипед. Наверняка наличие такого функционала заставило бы Вас задуматься **о решении самой задачи**, а не о том, какими инструментами ее решать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем тулить итераторы, где они не нужны? Почему просто не вызвать метод at у вектора и не переживать.

```
T getFunctionValue(int _number)
{
    return functionsVector.at(number);
}
```

Comment: теперь ругается на это

    functionsVector = new vector<T>();


    no match for 'operator=' in '((cFunctionVector<cFunction*>*)this)->cFunctionVector<cFunction*>::functionsVector = (operator new(12u), (<statement>, ((std::vector<cFunction*, std::allocator<cFunction*> >*)<anonymous>)))'

Comment: а, не, понял ошибку, это же не указатель у меня. Тогда теперь другой вопрос, судя по всему элементы не добавляются, ибо при вызове getFunctionValue() ничего не возвращается, хотя было добавлено 2 элемента, да и плюс при этом getAmount() возвращает 4

Comment: я бы тоже ругался бы.
зачем вызывать new для поля, которое не является указателем?

В данном случае, вначале вызывается конструктор, а потом оператор присваивания. А его нет... 

Если смотреть в код, то строка `functionsVector = new vector<T>();` не нужна.

Comment: >> и плюс при этом getAmount() возвращает 4
логично. Вы же вначале неявно добавляете один элемент, потом ещё один явно. `functionsVector.resize(functionsVector.size()+1);` не нужен, push_back сам его сделает. не путаете с `reserve` ?

А ничего не возвращается потому что запрашиваете 0 элемент. А он "пустой".

Comment: о, спасибо большое, да, перепутал с reserve, и кстати, если не делать reserve, то все равно при добавлении на каждый добавленный элемент размер вектора дважды инкрементируется, при использовании reverse все работает адекватно

Comment: @MorkOFF48: reverse или reserve?

Comment: дважды инкрементируется? смотрите внимательно код. Судя с того кода, что я вижу, подозреваю, что в другим местах ещё веселее.

Comment: @VladD: reserve

Answer (score 5):

А почему бы и вправду не написать

```
typename vector<T>::iterator it = ...
```

? Вот обсуждение, почему это требуется стандартом: [Why do I need to use typedef typename in g++ but not VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642229/why-do-i-need-to-use-typedef-typename-in-g-but-not-vs).

Comment: сделать можно, но в данном случае есть значительно проще и красивее решения.

Comment: а кстати по поводу итератора, он не будет работать быстрее, чем at в данном случае (как к примеру в случае с указателями на массивы)?

Comment: хотите скорость - используйте `operator[]`. Но он, как и Ваш код имеет один недостаток - не проверяет выход за пределы. А вот at(index)  - проверяет. 
думаю at может  оказаться медленее Вашего кода, но не думайте сейчас об этом. Всегда можно заменить на `[]`. 

А вот код с итератором в данном случае - жуть, которую не нужно писать.

Comment: @KoVadim: я хотел показать топикстартеру, как решить проблему локально. По поводу глобальной оптимизации, я бы просто заменил `cFunctionVector<T>` на `vector<T>` при текущем состоянии кода. Но возможно код упрощён, чтобы не нагружать нас несущественными деталями, поэтому я не рискнул оптимизировать глобально.

Comment: @MorkOFF48: в принципе, хороший оптимизирующий компилятор (например, gcc или MSVC) произведёт один и тот же код. Так что большой разницы, пожалуй, нет. Однако, зубры старого поколения могут посчитать код неоптимальным, поскольку они привыкли работать на слабеньких компиляторах и оптимизировать вручную.

Comment: @VladD вариант хорош. Вот только в данном случае лишнее усложнение не нужно. А код, который привел ТС, вряд ли упрощен. Его ещё упрощать и упрощать:)

О замене сразу на `vector<T>` я тоже думал, но думаю это не нужно ему.

Comment: @KoVadim: просто если код упрощён, непонятно, зачем нужен класс: ничего нового по сравнению с vector<T> он не делает. Впрочем, это вопрос скорее к ТС, чем к вам.

Comment: зачем нужен класс, мне понятно. Это же классическая методика при программировании - создание специализированных классов для решения проблемы (то есть задачи). В будущем класс получит новые, специализированные методы. А пока он такой.

В противном случае придется делать либо отдельные функции, либо размазывать методы по другим классам. А это уже плохая идея.

Плюс, у такого подхода есть хороший плюс при отладке. Ставим бряку внутри класса и отлавливаем все вызовы. А иначе придется искать по всему коду и смотреть во все методы.

Answer (score 4):

Начнем с первой проблемы. Переменная     functionsVector определяется как вектор типа T

```
vector<T> functionsVector;
```

Но в конструкторе почему-то присутствует такая строка

```
   functionsVector = new vector<T>();
```

Оператор new возвращает указатель на созданный объект. Думаю, ошибочность этой строки сами увидите.

Как сделать грамотно

```
cFunctionVector() : functionsVector () {}
```

По поводу typename в функции T getFunctionValue(int _number), то он должен быть обязательно. Но использование итератора в данном контексте - маразм (об этом уже писали).

Также очень плохо написан другой конструктор. Надо бы так

```
cFunctionVector(const vector<T> & _functionsVector): 
      functionsVector (_functionsVector)   {}
```

Comment: @mikillskegg, вот чего я не понимаю, так это **зачем вообще нужен класс cFunctionVector?**

Неужели нельзя обойтись просто вектором для адресов функций?

Comment: В случае нормальной рабочей программы это было бы абсолютным быдлокодом. Просто сделать typedef. Но в качестве упражнения - почему бы и нет. Цель моей речи было указать на принципиальные ошибки, чтобы ТС чему-то на будущее научился.

Comment: Для упражнения, конечно. Тренировка на простой, но более-менее осмысленной задачке.

Comment: Хотя, с другой стороны, если нужно расширить интерфейс, то лучше было бы здесь использовать наследование.

Comment: @mikillskegg: от вектора наследоваться не получится: у него невиртуальный деструктор. Так что The Law of Big Three будет нарушено.

Comment: Как раз наследование здесь даже вредно. Конечно, можно было сделать приватным, но оно ничем не лучше.

Comment: @VladD, это имеет значение, если в производном классе надо  освобождать какие-то ресурсы (или еще что-то важное делать) в деструкторе. Если нет - то это неважно. Вспоминаем, зачем нужны виртуальные деструкторы.

@KoVadim, можно конкретнее - почему?

Comment: @mikillskegg: не вызванный деструктор = undefined behaviour, разве нет? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2034936/276994

update: вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8599332/276994) говорится, что вызов не того конструктора таки undefined behaviour со ссылкой на релевантную часть стандарта.

Comment: ОК, спасибо, убедили. Но если не использовать позднего связывания, то проблем не будет и в случае с наследованием. В таком случае ТС прав и надо использовать делегирование и has-a.